# Spectrum of a positive operator in $B(H)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

We know that for $T\in B(H)$. If $T$ is positive, then $T$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma(T)\subset R^{+}$.
Do we have the inverse ie: if $T$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma(T)\subset R^{+}$. $T$ is positive.

where $T$ is said to be positive in case $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in H$, $H$ is a Hilbert space.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you know about the continuous functional calculus for a normal element of a C*-algebra? One can use this to immediately get that a normal element (in any C*-algebra) is positive if and only if it has non-negative spectrum.

Comment: yes, I know a bit of the functional calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint linear operator on a Hilbert space. Then
$$
                   \lambda=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle
$$
is in the spectrum of $T$. Therefore, if $\sigma(T)\subset[0,\infty)$, then $\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle \ge 0$.

**Proof:** To prove what you want, let $\lambda=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$, and note that $\lambda$ satisfies
$$
                          0 \le \langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle.
$$
Therefore $[x,y] = \langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle$ has all the properties of an inner product, except possibly strict positivity ($[x,x] \ge 0$ is always non-negative.) So the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
                   |[x,y]|^2 \le [x,x][y,y] \\
                 |\langle (T-\lambda I)x,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle\langle(T-\lambda I)y,y\rangle
$$
Now set $y=(T-\lambda I)x$ in order to obtain
\begin{align}
               \|(T-\lambda I)x\|^4 &\le \langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle\cdot\langle(T-\lambda I)^2x,(T-\lambda I)x\rangle \\
                      &\le \langle(T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle\|(T-\lambda I)\|\|(T-\lambda I)x\|\|(T-\lambda I)x\| \\
              \|(T-\lambda I)x\|^2 &\le\|(T-\lambda I)\|\langle(T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle
\end{align}
If you choose a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_n\}$ so that $\langle (T-\lambda I)x_n,x_n\rangle\rightarrow 0$, it follows that $(T-\lambda I)x_n\rightarrow 0$, which forces $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$. $\;\;\blacksquare$

Comment: thank you very much, could you give me title of the book where i can find this and more to improve my knowledge.?

Comment: @TryingToLearn : What is your background? Taylor and Lay, *Functional Analysis* is probably out of print. It's a classical introduction for many topics in Functional Analysis. Based on the fact that Amazon has a used copy listed for $855, I assume it is out of print, and posting this download link would be just fine. http://bookfi.net/dl/1463459/c0a8f7

Comment: thank you very much, I started reading Walter Rudin and Conway. I will look with attention at Taylor and Lay, Functional Analysis. If you have any other suggestions related to functional analysis and operator theory, it will be great.

Comment: @TryingToLearn : I would also highly recommend the text by Peter Lax. He has a way of making things seem natural.

Comment: @TryingToLearn : If you are interested in an excellent introduction to Spectral Theory that is aimed toward Operator Algebras, then you can't go wrong with William B. Arveson's "A Short Course in Spectral Theory". Arveson was an amazing talent in Operator Algebras, and he had a way of making things look simple in a field that is not simple.

Comment: @TryingToLearn : If you like my answer, then check the mark next to the question to accept the answer. You can +1 it if you really like it.