# Let A ∈ B(H) be self-adjoint and $f$ is a positive continuous function on $\sigma(A)$, Show $f(A)$ is a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

> Question   Let  H a Hilbert space and A ∈ B(H) be self-adjoint and $f$ is a positive continuous function on $\sigma(A)$, Show $f(A)$ is a positive operator,

> I have a long and complicated approach and ask to know a lot of results. Can we make it simple?

1- A being self-adjoint, its spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is compact. Since f is continuous on $\sigma(A)$, we can approximate it by a sequence of polynomial functions on $\sigma(A)$. We can assume that f is a polynomial

2- Since A is self-adjoint and f polynomial, a spectral analysis theoreme shows that $\sigma(f(A))=f(\sigma(A))$
and since f is positive on $\sigma(A)$, then $\sigma(f(A))$ is positive

3- I remind this spectral analysis theorem
Let A ∈ B(H) be self-adjoint and let $f:\sigma (A)\to \mathbb {C}$ continuous . Then f(A) is self-adjoint iff f is real-valued.

We deduce that f(A) is self-adjoint and since $\sigma(f(A))$ is positive then , f(A) is a positive operator see for example [Spectrum of a positive operator in $B(H)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825916/spectrum-of-a-positive-operator-in-bh)

**Addition  Martin Argerami asked You don't say how you define the functional calculus.**

Let K be a compact of $\mathbb R$.

1. We denote by C(K; $\mathbb K$) the $\mathbb K$-vector space of continuous functions from K to $\mathbb K$.
   We equip this space with the uniform convergence
2. $\mathcal { P}(K)$ denotes the vector subspace of C(K; $\mathbb K$) consisting of the polynomials of K[X]
   restricted to K.

> Let T ∈ L(H) be a self-adjoint operator and P ∈ $\mathcal { P}$(σ(T)). be
> Q, R ∈ K[X] two extensions from P to K. Then, we have
> Q(T) = R(T).
> We can therefore define the operator P(T) ∈ L(H) by setting P(T) := Q(T), where Q ∈ K[X]
> is any extension from P to K

> Let T ∈ L(H) be a self-adjoint operator. Then, the map Φ defined
> from $\mathcal { P}$(σ(T)) to L(H) by
> Φ(P) := P(T),
> extends uniquely to C(σ(T); $\mathbb K$) in an isometric linear map $\psi$ .
> Thus, for any f ∈ C(σ(T); $\mathbb K$), we can define f(T) ∈ L(H) by setting
> f(T) := $\psi(f)$.

Comment: If $A$ is normal, then $A \ge 0$ if and only if $\sigma(A) \subset [0,\infty)$. This is a classic result.  Now use the Spectral Mapping thm: $\sigma(f(A)) = f(\sigma(A)) \subset [0,\infty)$ to deduce that  $f(A) \ge 0$.

Comment: This is exactly my proof except that the Spectral Mapping thm is valid for a polynomial function and I explained why f(A) is also self-adjoint

Comment: The spectral mapping theorem holds for each function that is continuous in an open neighbourdhood of the spectrum.

Comment: @ Adriano 8 I did not know this result,   see theorem 13.9 https://tqft.net/web/teaching/current/Analysis3/LectureNotes/13.Spectral.theory.pdf

Comment: Your approach requires that if $f\ge 0$ on $\sigma(A)$ there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ **nonnegative** on $\sigma(A)$ and  convergent uniformly to $f$ on $\sigma(A).$ This can be achieved by the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Another proof without using the Spectral Mapping thm ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:=\sqrt f$ and $B:=g(A).$ Then, $B^*=B$ and $A=B^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Your map $\psi:C(\sigma(A))\to B(H)$ is not only linear and isometric, but multiplicative and $*$-preserving. In particular, it preserves positivity. So if $f\geq0$, then $f(A)=\psi(f)\geq0$.

Comment: Martin Argerami H is a Hilbert space. we are therefore looking for a simple proof, which does not require very fine arguments

Comment: What's your "simple" definition of $f(A)$?

Comment: I edited to explain

Comment: Your $\psi$ is precisely the Gelfand-Naimark representation.

Comment: thanks i didn't know that